# Compare two Django fields to be identical, raise Validation error if not

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am putting together a Non Disclosure Form(NDA) on my clients site and need to add some field comparison validation.  When someone wants more information on one of my clients listings, they would register a name and email (AllAuth) and upon verifying their email, they would immediately be shown the NDA form which would have already inserted their `user.first_name` and `user.last_name` at the top of the form.  At the bottom of the form after other fields to fill out, they would type their signature in a field that would have the validation -`{{ nda.user_signature }}`.

I did my best to write a filter that would concatenate the Django user fields to create a signature variable and then compare the value of user_signature matches, if not, it would raise an error.  Below is custom tag attempt. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
from django import template
from django.db.models import F
from django.forms import forms

register = template.Library()


    @register.filter(name='confirm_sig')
    def confirm_sig(value):
        delta = value
        signature = F('user.first_name') + "" + F('user.last_name')

        if delta != signature:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Signatures must match first and last name")
        return delta
```

**UPDATED**
Here is my form currently

```
class BaseModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('auto_id', '%s')
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for field_name in self.fields:
            field = self.fields.get(field_name)
            if field:
                field.widget.attrs.update({
                    'placeholder': field.label,
                    'class': 'form-control placeholder-no-fix'
                })


class NonDisclosureForm(BaseModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NonDisclosure
        fields = ['user_signature', 'user_street', 'user_email', 'user_city', 'user_state', 'user_zip', 'phone', 'cash_on_hand', 'value_of_securities', 'equity_in_real_estate', 'other']

class NdaCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = NonDisclosureForm
    template_name = 'nda/nda_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        form.instance.created_by = self.request.user
        return super(NdaCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in a filter, rather than in a form?

Comment: Because I don't know any better I guess :)  Still learning and trying to figure things out before posting here.  Can you help me out?  Thank you.

Comment: See the [form validation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/), in particular the section [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) which answers your question directly.